# levelplot does not display content

Tags: r, levelplot

I am new to the function level plot. Ich have x,y,z that I want to visualize level plot the following way:

```
> require(lattice)



> head(z)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]  4.5  4.7  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.7
[2,]  4.5  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.7
[3,]  4.5  4.7  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.7  4.6  4.7
[4,]  4.5  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.7
[5,]  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.7
[6,]  4.5  4.7  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.7

> head(y)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    5
[5,]    7
[6,]   10

> head(x)
[1] "2013-01-03 04:30:00 GMT" "2013-01-03 04:45:00 GMT" "2013-01-03 05:00:00 GMT"
[4] "2013-01-03 05:15:00 GMT" "2013-01-03 05:30:00 GMT" "2013-01-03 05:45:00 GMT"
```

z represents water temperatures and y water depths

I want to plot the data the following way:

```
> levelplot(z~x*y)
```

The axes and legend get plotted correctly, but the content is not plotted at all. Can anyone help me??

Best regards, 
Philip

Answer (score 3):

Although I have no idea why what you tried didn't work, it seems that using `levelplot.array` instead of `levelplot.formula` works correctly (with `aspect="fill"` specified):

```
x <- as.POSIXct(x) #make sure x are POSIXct and not just characters
levelplot(z, row.values=x, column.values=y, aspect="fill")
```

[image]